# Calling em.merge() on child entity gives parent object in return while using SINGLE_TABLE inheritence

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, entity, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Eclipselink 2.6.3 with JPA 2.0

I have an issue with SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy as you can see I have class A which is extended by Z & X. When I query and fetch List of Z or X entities and try to change something and update them one by one, in the process when I call **em.merge()** for fetching merged clone object it gives back class A which is strange.

As I already have class extractor which decides what class should be returned based on a specific field value.

This issue is intermittent and can't be replicated every time, I've also debugged in UnitOfWorkImpl method

```
 public Object mergeCloneWithReferences(Object rmiClone, MergeManager manager) {
        if (rmiClone == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //this line should always give correct entity back.. but doesnt happen why ?
        ClassDescriptor descriptor = getDescriptor(rmiClone);
        if ((descriptor == null) || descriptor.isDescriptorTypeAggregate()) {
            if (manager.getCascadePolicy() == MergeManager.CASCADE_BY_MAPPING){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ExceptionLocalization.buildMessage("not_an_entity", new Object[]{rmiClone}));
            }
            return rmiClone;
        }

        //CR#2272
        logDebugMessage(rmiClone, "merge_clone_with_references");

        ObjectBuilder builder = descriptor.getObjectBuilder();
        Object implementation = builder.unwrapObject(rmiClone, this);

        Object mergedObject = manager.mergeChanges(implementation, null, this);
        if (isSmartMerge()) {
            return builder.wrapObject(mergedObject, this);
        } else {
            return mergedObject;
        }
    }
```

Can someone point out what's going wrong ?

Class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_A")
@Customizer(ACustomizer.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@ClassExtractor(AExtractor.class)
@InstantiationCopyPolicy
@Cacheable
@Cache( alwaysRefresh=true,
        refreshOnlyIfNewer=true,
        expiry=300000,      
        coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
public class A implements Serializable {
@Column(name="ABC")
private String abc;
```

//some fields

```
}
```

Class Z

```
@Entity
@Customizer(ZCustomizer.class)
public class Z extends A{
 //some fields 

}
```

class X

```
   @Entity
    public class X extends A{
     //some fields 

    }
```

Comment: When you query, are you returned your subclass or the parent?  The getDescriptor method looks at the class passed in, and returns the associated descriptor.  If it isn't found, it looks at the class' parent class and up the hierarchy until it finds a descriptor.  If there wasn't one for the X subclass but is one for A, it means that X did not get loaded or included in the persistence unit.

Comment: @Chris query returns proper entity as required (i.e child class) still it ends up with returning parent class while calling em.merge()

Comment: How did you persist it?  What you put in is what you should get out until the context/cache gets cleared.  Once it is cleared, JPA is responsible from building the entity from the database based on the mappings on hand.  You should be able to check your extractor method and what it returns, and if this is getting called.  Another possibility is that you have a classloader issue, so that the child object (and its class) have been loaded from a different one then the one used to initially load the persistence unit. Not sure how the parent would be found though.